# Functions inside PHP classes and memory usage

Tags: php, function, class, memory

Do you think it is a good practice to put all functions related to an object inside it's class, like the following example:

```
class User
{
    var $id;
    var $username;

    public function __construct()
    { 
    $this->loadPosts();
    $this->loadSettings();
    }

    public function loadPosts()
    {
    .... code here ...
    }

    public function loadSettings()
    {
    .... code here ...
    }
}
```

This is just an example, real class will have more properties and functions.

I was thinking about puting these functions outside the class in a seperate php file, to save memory when we have a lot of user objects loaded. Although it is much easier to read the code with functions inside the class for me.

What do you think?

Comment: Before you compromise your architecture, *prove that this coding style actually influences your memory usage*.

Comment: Is memory usage a issue in the script?

Comment: Yes memory usage is critical for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might. If you have a central controller that handles certain object types or methods.

That said, it's probably worth it to keep them encapsulated. The benefits are probably higher than a possibly negligible performance improvement (which would be speculative, unless you can refactor and compare).

Big benefits:

- Readability when handing off the code to someone else
- Readability when revisiting the code at a later date
- IDE Code completion

I personally think that that time is better spent doing something else, unless, of course, you test and find out that moving a method out into a singleton or something is quite superior.

So it depends, but probably not

Answer (score 0):

If you must call the inner methods `loadPosts()` and `loadSettings()` then keeping them as class methods seems to be a good idea.

To save on memory, simply don't call the methods upon __construct().
It will be more memory efficient to call them only when actually needed to view the output.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to something like this. A couple things to consider:

1. Maintainability. How easy is it going to be to maintain this code? If you have code scattered about, it might be harder to maintain, especially if it is a large application. If it's a smaller app, it may not be that big of a deal.
2. Size. Is this a large app or small app? If its small, there is not need to over complicate things. If it's large, it might make more sense to have 'function' files and other helper classes. But if you only have couple files, you might not need it.
3. Time. Is it going to be harder for you to use the functions if you move them? Will it complicate things?
4. Resources. How much of your resources are you using? How much load time will you save? Is this a small that will grow larger down the road? If so, it might make sense to worry about  things like this. If it is a simple photo app that won't grow, then resources aren't that big of a deal, and the time you spend saving resources will be wasted.

Ultimately, there is no right answer to this, but hopefully this will give you a couple things to think about.

Comment: "Ultimately, there is no right answer to this", in which case the question should be closed as 'Primarily opinion based' rather than answered.